# Changes(update) not commited to multiple columns using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

i am trying the linq to sql query using button but the change does not commit.

here is the code which i am using:

```
using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
        {
            var user = (from a in context.User_profiles
                        where a.user_id == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["user_id"])
                        select a).FirstOrDefault();


            user.email = _Email.Text;
            user.first_name = _FirstName.Text;
            user.last_name = _LastName.Text;
            user.phone = _Phone.Text;
            user.cell = _Cell.Text;
            user.fax = _Fax.Text;
            user.address = _Address.Text;
            user.zip_code = _ZipCode.Text;
            user.country = _Country.SelectedItem.Text;

            context.SubmitChanges();
         }
```

Comment: When you debug, can you verify that the user is being returned?

Comment: @W3AVE...yes it does return the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems correct. I think you are missing something else. So i suggest you should try some debugging; 
First make sure to wrap your code inside `null check` always;

```
if(user !=null)
{
       user.email = _Email.Text;
            user.first_name = _FirstName.Text;
            user.last_name = _LastName.Text;
            user.phone = _Phone.Text;
            user.cell = _Cell.Text;
            user.fax = _Fax.Text;
            user.address = _Address.Text;
            user.zip_code = _ZipCode.Text;
            user.country = _Country.SelectedItem.Text;

            context.User_profiles.Attach(user);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
            context.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Secondly, for debugging purposes, write some const string values to see if really you are posting data like this;

```
user.email = _Email.Text;
            user.first_name = "test1";
            user.last_name = _LastName.Text;
           .........
            context.SubmitChanges();
```

And third, don't forget, debugger is your best friend :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
using (Property_dbDataContext context = new Property_dbDataContext())
        {
            var user = (from a in context.User_profiles
                        where a.user_id == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["user_id"])
                        select a).FirstOrDefault();


            user.email = _Email.Text;
            user.first_name = _FirstName.Text;
            user.last_name = _LastName.Text;
            user.phone = _Phone.Text;
            user.cell = _Cell.Text;
            user.fax = _Fax.Text;
            user.address = _Address.Text;
            user.zip_code = _ZipCode.Text;
            user.country = _Country.SelectedItem.Text;

            context.User_profiles.Attach(user);
            context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(user, EntityState.Modified);
            context.SubmitChanges();
         }
```